# Evitar desplazamiento de celdas Excel desde VB (Conexión ODBC)

Tags: excel, odbc, vb

estoy realizando una macro para Excel 2013 usando VB que conecta con una base de datos postgresql mediante un ODBC.
Mi problema es el siguiente: cuando hago una consulta que por ejemplo devuelve 3 columnas y después realizo otra que devuelva 5, al refrescar el contenido de una consulta a otra se desplaza mi hoja de cálculo, en este caso, 3 columnas a la derecha. Adjunto el código de la consulta y capturas de imagen para que se entienda mejor.

```
If ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Count > 0 Then
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1)
    .Sql = sqlstring
    .Refresh
    End With
Else
    connstring = _
    "ODBC;DSN=XXX;Database=XXX;PWD=XXX;SERVER=XXX;PORT=;UID=XXX;SSLmode=disable;ReadOnly=0;Protocol=7.4;FakeOidIndex=0;ShowOidColumn=0;RowVersioning=0;ShowSystemTables=0;Fetch=100;UnknownSizes=0;MaxVarcharSize=255;MaxLongVarcharSize=8190;Debug=0;CommLog=0;UseDeclareFetch=0;TextAsLongVarchar=1;UnknownsAsLongVarchar=0;BoolsAsChar=1;Parse=0;ExtraSysTablePrefixes=;LFConversion=1;UpdatableCursors=1;TrueIsMinus1=0;BI=0;ByteaAsLongVarBinary=1;UseServerSidePrepare=1;LowerCaseIdentifier=0;XaOpt=1"
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, _
        Destination:=Range("A1"), Sql:=sqlstring)
    .Refresh
    End With
End If
```

Capturas:
Primera consulta:
[image: Consulta 1]
Segunda consulta (Se produce un desplazamiento, las columnas K:O sobran) :
[image: Consulta 2]

Comment: Hola! Dices que sobran las columnas K:O pero en las imágenes has cortado el encabezado de las columnas. Entiendo que los datos empiezan en la columna A, no?

Comment: Si, perdón se me paso en la imagen.